# Granting authorization when user signs in

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social

I was wondering if there's a way to grant an authorization for the user when the user connects through facebook or any other provider so he could have access to specific resource.

I was thing about implementing this using **ConnectInterceptor** interface but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can overrider the `authenticate` method in your own provider that implements the  `AuthenticationProvider`, you can add your special roles into the `Authentication`.